# Streaming video over LAN network

Tags: javascript, html, video, streaming, jwplayer

I'm looking for a way to stream video to a local network. There would be around 1000 viewers, if not more, and this would have to be via a browser (most viewers have Internet Explorer, but Chrome and Firefox support would be nice too). Since it's company policy, not all users have internet access, so this would have to be hosted internally on the company's network. The source of the video will be both a video file and a live feed from a webcam.

On the receiving end I plan on serving the feed via JW Player, but I'm having troubles on how to stream the video.

I've been trying with VLC Media Player to no success, and I'm searching for another method (or instructions on how to do it correctly). In general, any help would be appreciated as I'm having a total brain fart moment. Currently I'm stating on the video file part first, and when that's running I'm going to focus on the webcam part.

Thanks!

Comment: Your company's "no internet" policy seems to be the problem here.

Comment: I fail to see that as the problem, I could stream my desktop using Gmax FLV encoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I succeeded on using VLC for the stream, but when the viewers began to scale up, the stream began to slowdown fast.Then by using Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder to make a RTMP stream from the video source, and using Wowza as the streaming server, the stream is up and running with no noticeable slowdown when the viewers grow.

I hope this solution works when the event is due (next tuesday).

Answer (score 0):

As your players are mostly in Internet Explorer, the easiest way for you to support live streaming would be using Flash RTMP streaming. This solution is not *state of the art*, and in fact might become obsolete within a couple of years, but it would be the best solution for a LAN in which most clients are IE. I suggest looking at Adobe's [FMS](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family.html) or [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com) as streaming servers. You can find tutorials on how to set up the system, for live or on-demand streaming, on their websites ([1](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/getting_started.html), [2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/beginner_live_fms3.html), [3](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?3-quick-start-guide)).

You should also consider implementing multicast for the live stream, as it will prevent the 1000s of concurrent streams congesting your LAN. AFAIK you can only do that with [FMS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/amazonec2/WS6fc2df2b6d2ce24359910e2812c396a83eb-7ff8.2.html#WS6fc2df2b6d2ce24359910e2812c396a83eb-7ff3.2).